# Django form validation/saving for a template with varying quantity and order of text, images, and forms

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a Django app where a user (say a researcher or a teacher) can create content for other users (participants or students) where any given page may include any number of content items (such as surveys questions, text, and/or images), and these items can be arranged by the teacher in any order on a page.

I'm taking an approach similar to the last chapters (10-12) of the book *Django by Example*. The app from those chapters comes very close to giving an example of my case using an e-Learning platform app, but they only allow teachers to create Content like Text and Images, they do not allow teachers to create survey questions for students. Here is the general approach that I am following.

**The book models content for text and images for a given page like so:**

```
class Content(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='contents')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                     limit_choices_to={'model__in':('text',
                                                                    'image')})
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    item = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    order = OrderField(blank=True, for_fields=['page'])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']


class ItemBase(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
         abstract = True

    def render(self):
         return render_to_string('courses/content/{}.html'.format(
                   self._meta.model_name), {'item': self})


class Text(ItemBase):
    content = models.TextField()

class Image(ItemBase):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='images')
```

There's an interface for teachers to fill out and order this content for a page.

**Content is rendered within a template like so:**

```
<div class="page">
    {% for content in page.contents.all %}
        {% with item=content.item %}
            <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
            {{ item.render }}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**And the html used in the render method for a Text Content is simply:**

```
{{item.content|linebreaks|safe }}
```

I don't find it difficult to extend this with QuestionTypes that extend ItemBase (similar to Text and Image models), as well as creating a StudentAnswer model for storing answers in the database.

I would probably override ItemBase render and put it into the QuestionType model so that I could pass a StudentAnswer model form into the context for the QuestionType html file.

I could then just have the html that is rendered contain {{ form }} for simplicity sake, and we now have a question that acts like any other content item and can be ordered with all of the others. This assumes that the HTML that contains the content has a form tag that encompass all of the rendered content items.

**My problem** is handling the POST request in the view. I have no idea how to validate and save answers from multiple forms on any given single page generated in this way. Examples I find assume a consistent number of forms that you know by name and are of different types.

I've also played around with the idea of creating a single dynamically generated form, but the examples I've seen for that assume you will loop through the fields in the template and display them in order rather than my requirement that a teacher determines the order which may include text or images in-between questions.

Is there a way to create what I'm looking for or can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look into formsets, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Formsets aren't going to help with this problem because they are for models of the same type. These forms can be different question types. Even if they were the same type, I run into the same problem as I mentioned with Dynamically generated forms. That is, all examples I see for rendering those forms in the template involve iterating over the fields in a for loop. I don't see how I could order text and images in-between forms and fields in a particular order if I render them in html with a for loop like that.

Comment: perhaps this will give you ideas http://www.joshuakehn.com/2013/7/18/multiple-django-forms-in-one-form.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Haha, but that's the other problem in the examples I find that I already mentioned (your first comment hit the other one). Examples like that are for fixed amount of forms, and in that case, one has the luxury of knowing that exactly those two forms will be on the page and how they will be arranged in the template. I can't loop through forms and fields because there might be stuff in-between, but I also can't just list them out and place them where I want because the forms and field types vary in quantity and position from page to page.